# Gutenberg sidebar example does not update meta field in the database

Tags: sidebar, block-editor

Gutenberg example for creating sidebar
https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/
does not keep what is entered in the box. After refreshing the page, entered content is gone end text box is empty. I guess it is some kind of REST problem?

I just checked, when updating post, meta field is sent via POST request, therefore it is not a REST problem:

{"meta":{"sidebar_plugin_meta_block_field":"Jozica1"},"content":" ... etc

PHP Code:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    if (is_admin()) {
        wp_register_script( 'gmk-sidebar-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sidebar-panel.js',
        [ 'wp-plugins', 'wp-edit-post', 'wp-element', 'wp-components', 'wp-data' ]
        );
        wp_register_style( 'gmk-sidebar-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin-guten-sidebar.css' );

        register_post_meta( '', 'sidebar_plugin_meta_block_field', array(
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'single' => true,
            'type' => 'string',
        ) );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Please don't add the answer in your question please add a proper answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/329760/30597

Answer (score 2):

Registration of meta field must happen outside of admin area check. I had it enclosed in `if (is_admin)` check, so it was only happening when it passed this test. This was incorrect.

The question is duplicate and original question and answer are here:
[Plugin Sidebar is not Saving Meta Attribute to Post/Page after "Update"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329760/plugin-sidebar-is-not-saving-meta-attribute-to-post-page-after-update)